# How to make a datagridview display the contents of an array?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a 1d array `listOfValues`. It contains double values. I want to display its values into a datagridview named as `dataGridVal`.

I did 
`dataGridVal.Source = listOfValues` but its not working.

Did I miss something???

Comment: You want to display them in a single row/column ?

Answer (score 3):

`DataGridView` binds its columns to properties of items in data source. Thus double type do not have any properties, you can't bind directly to that type.

HINT: you can project double values into anonymous objects:

```
dataGridVal.DataSource = listOfValues.Select(d => new { Value = d }).ToArray();
```